# Torquebox stomplet session empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, stomp, torquebox

I'm trying to implement user authentication for web sockets in Torquebox, and according to everything on the internet, I should be able to access the HTTP session from within a stomplet if I'm running the web app along side the stomp server, which I am.

My configuration looks something like this

```
web do
  context '/'
  host 'localhost'
end

stomp do
  host 'localhost'
end

stomplet GlobalStomplet do
  route '/live/socket'
end
```

I've tried also commenting out the web and stomp blocks but nothing changes.

Basically, the sockets are working, I can connect, and subscribe. In my stomplet, the `on_subscribe` method has a few debug lines

```
Rails.logger.debug "SESSION = #{subscriber.session}"
Rails.logger.debug "SESSION 2 = #{subscriber.getSession.getAttributeNames}"
Rails.logger.debug "SOCKET SESSION = #{TorqueBox::Session::ServletStore.load_session_data(subscriber.getSession)}"
```

And any other combination of these sort of things, but in every case I am given an empty session. The only exception, is when I explicitly load the session (as in the last debug line above) my session contains a session ID and something like `TORQUEBOX_INITIAL_KEYS`, but the session ID is not the HTTP session, and is simply something like `session-1` and nothing useful.

I have an initialiser in the rails app setting up the torque box session store

```
MyApp::Application.config.session_store :torquebox_store, {
  key: '_app_key'
}
```

I don't receive any exceptions from anything so I assume there are no obvious problems, but I've tried everything I can think of and still don't have a session that I can use.

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using Torquebox 3.1.0, Rails 4, and jRuby 1.7.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems I wasn't doing anything wrong per-se, but there seems to be an underlying bug in Torquebox (filing a bug report now)

It seems as though torque box web apps are quite happy with me assigning a custom key for the session store, and every works as expected. Unfortunately, it seems as though the stomplets are looking for the normal `JSESSIONID` only, and ignore the custom defined key.

To confirm, I remove the custom key, and it worked. I then reintroduced it, and again it stopped working. With the key still in place, I manually set the JSESSIONID cookie value, and reconnected and suddenly my session appeared.